# Visual Studio Multibyte Enabled but not detected

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So, i have this piece of code to create error functions:

```cpp
void Error(const char* error_title, const char* error_message)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, error_message, error_title, NULL);
    exit(-1);

}
```

I saw the problem and quickly knew i needed to set the project properties from Unicode to MultiByte. The thing is that the error is still there.

I was following a YouTube tutorial and it seemed to work for other people... I thought Visual Studio glitched or something so I restarted the application but it still says the same error...

Error Output:

```
An argument type "const char*" is not compatible with a parameter type "LPCWSTR"
```

Comment: You still have Unicode active.  If you just want to change this one function call to use narrow strings, instead of changing project properties, use `MessageBoxA`.

Comment: I got more functions that use the Mutlibyte...

Comment: Since your input is `const char*`, use `MessageBoxA()` directly instead, as `MessageBox()` is clearly being mapped to `MessageBoxW()`. Then you won't run into this issue no matter whether the project is set to Unicode or MultiByte. Same with your other API calls. You should explicitly use the `A` or `W` versions directly, depending on the type of data they are working with. Stay away from the `TCHAR` versions, if you can. `TCHAR` was invented to help migrate people from ANSI to Unicode in the days of Win9x. It has no real merit in modern coding anymore (unless you need to still support Win9x).